# Kernel is Orthocomplement of Image of Adjoint (Unbounded Case)

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I understand that this question has been posted many times, but I'd like to cover it in the unbounded case.

Let $A: D(A) \subset X \to Y$ where $X,Y$ are infinite dimensional Banach Spaces, and $D(A)  \subset X$ is a dense subspace of $X$.

As such, the adjoint of $A$ denoted $A^*$ is defined, $A^*:D(A^*) \subset Y^* \to X^*$, and satisfies the relation:

$$
\langle A^* y^*, x\rangle = \langle y^*, Ax\rangle
$$
for any $y^* \in D(A^*)$.

I would like to show that if $A$ is **closed** then:
$$
\ker (A) = \mathrm{img}(A^*)^\perp
$$
Here the orthogonal complement of a subspace $S \leq X^*$ (a subspace of the dual space) is defined as:
$$
S^\perp = \{x \in X: \langle x^*, x\rangle = 0 \text{ for all } x^* \in S\}
$$
Note that in particular, it is not a subset of the bidual $X^{**}$ but a subset of $X$ itself (a smaller space).

Showing that $\ker(A) \subset \mathrm{img}(A^*)^\perp$ is not difficult. However, I struggle with the reverse inclusion $\mathrm{img}(A^*)^\perp \subset\ker (A)$. Taking $x \in \mathrm{img}(A^*)^\perp$, we have that:
$$
\langle x^*, x\rangle = 0
$$
for all $x^*$ that can be written as $A^*y*$ for some $y^* \in D(A^*)$. Hence:
$$
0 = \langle x^*, x\rangle = \langle A^*y^*, x\rangle = \langle y^*, Ax\rangle
$$
So - for every $y^* \in D(A^*)$ we have that $\langle y^*, Ax\rangle = 0$. At this point, if $A^*$ was defined on the whole of $Y^*$, we could use Hahn-Banach (more precisely the fact that functionals separate points) to conclude that $Ax = 0$. But there seem to be no guarantees on $D(A^*)$ so I am not sure how to conclude.

I know so far I have not used the closedness assumption on $A$, although even if $A$ were not closed we know $A^*$ is closed. How should it be used?